# script the released version of my iOS app?

Tags: ios, scripting

I have a released app.  I would like to add a help functionality that runs a few simple scripts.  In other words, it programmatically highlights a button, presses it, highlights another button, presses it, and so on.  Is there a sensible way to do that?

I'm thinking of something like [UIAutomation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/UsingtheAutomationInstrument/UsingtheAutomationInstrument.html).  However the Apple doc linked above indicates that it requires that the app be code signed with a development profile.  So it won't work in a released app.

I'm not going to add somebody's library to do this.  So if the answer is that you can do it, but you have to either write a lot of code or link a third-party library, it will make more sense for me to hard-code everything in Objective C.

Comment: What's so bad about third party libraries?

Comment: More code to maintain . . . not worth it for the scripts I'd write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first:
Apple forbids App Store apps to interpret code so real scripting isn't allowed AFAICS but anyway:

technically:
if you don't want a ready made 3rd party lib
you'd need to write a lot of code (though a lot is relative ;)

**=> if the 'scripts' are simple, hardcode them in objC.**